# "Host" disabled mail() function on wordpress site?

Tags: php, wordpress, email

The contact form on http://www.allinsure.ca/contacts/ stopped working. I've disabled the form for now - it was created using Contact Form 7. Recently there has been a lot of email spam coming from that site, so my initial reaction is that the host may have disabled the mail() function. I called the host, and they said it wasn't them - everything was fine. Just to test, I tried resetting my wp-admin password... nothing. Here's the error:

> The e-mail could not be sent.
>   Possible reason: your host may have disabled the mail() function.

Seems like a host problem, right? I called again, argued a little bit, and left confused. It's not a host issue, it's something on the WordPress side.

Any help (resources, guesses) would be much appreciated.

Happy holidays!

Comment: simple test: `<?php var_dump(mail('you@example.com', 'test', 'can you hear me now?')); ?>` in a .php file, hit that url, and see what comes out. either you'll get your email, or php will output `(bool)false`, which means mail() failed to send. at that point you need to figure out where the problem is, which boils down a dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-form-doesnt-complete-sending-e-mail

Comment: Oh boy! Great suggestion here, I'll test

Comment: You can also check a [phpinfo](http://php.net/phpinfo) page and see what functions have been disabled by the host.

Comment: If nothing works you can try WP SMTP plugin since you're using WordPress > https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/ > It reconfigures the wp_mail() function to use SMTP instead of mail() and creates an options page to manage the settings.

Comment: Wow, leowebdev, you must be psychic because I just landed there. Tried Marc's suggestion and ended up with (bool)false, so just testing a few more things before reconfiguring to SMTP. Thanks so much for the suggestion!